# How to use JTable cell renderer without singletons?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, singleton

I'm using a DefaultTableCellRenderer to color rows of a table.  The color of a row is not inherent in the displayed table data, it's a property of underlying data used to build the table.  I'm using a table model to provide the cell data from the underlying data (which is passed to the table model explicitly, and carefully to avoid thread issues.)

In the renderer, I need access to the underlying data, or the table model.  Currently I could get away with a static or singleton, but in the future that might not be ideal.

What's the right way to access my data from a renderer?  My renderer is something like this:

```
class SummaryTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean   isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

        ... access my data here to derive color ...

        c.setBackground(color);
        return c; 
    } 
}
```

I'd hoped I could get my table model using table.getModel(), but that returns a type that I can't cast to my table model (which extends AbstractTableModel, not TableModel, the latter being an interface.)

I'm using JavaSE-1.6 for compatibility reasons, in case that matters.  Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using `table.getModel`, since it's passed to your method?

Comment: I repeat: "I'd hoped I could get my table model using table.getModel(), but that returns a type that I can't cast to my table model (which extends AbstractTableModel, not TableModel, the latter being an interface.)"

Comment: You've provide no information about how you are casting the table, what the actual table model is you're using or how you are using the render.  If you've done it right you should simply be able to use `YourTableModel model = (YourTableModel)table.getModel()` if this is not working then you've done something wrong else where in your code, which you are not showing us and makes it impossible for us help your further.

Comment: So, either cough up a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem or stop complaining about the fact that the answers you are receiving don't work

Comment: Hey, my apologies -- didn't mean to be crusty!    Retrying the cast, it worked, so clearly I was just doing it wrong somehow.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `getTableCellRendererComponent` method is passed a reference of the `JTable` when it is called...

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean   isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
```

Why not just use it to obtain a reference to the `TableModel`...

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
```

Now, depending on your needs, you may need to cast this to your implementation of the `TableModel`

Comment: Unfortunately, as I stated above, I can't cast the result of table.getModel() to my subclass of AbstractTableModel, so I can't call any methods other than those already a part of the TableModel interface, so I can't get at the underlying data.  Perhaps I'm simply casting it the wrong way.

Comment: Why can't you cast the resulting model?

Comment: My mistake!  Eclipse was reporting an error (can't convert), but no doubt I just goofed; sorry to take your time.